# Override max-length on the Title format field

Tags: craft3, titles, auto-generate

We're using entry properties in the Title format field to automate titles for some channels. However we've ran into the issue of this field having a max-length set on it. I understand why this exists when you create an entry. But when you're setting up the code to auto generate titles you can easily run longer than the allowed 255 characters.

[image]

Is there a way to change the max length or some way to get around this issue?

We've looked but haven't found any plugins to deal with this issue nor any clever ways to get around the current limitation. I've seen some posts about the max length but they relate to when you add entries. This is just about when you setup automated titles.

Comment: Probably worth posting as an issue over on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brad. I've posted it there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See reply from brandonkelly on GitHub for an alternative to adress this issue.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5132#issuecomment-544507473